# How can I pass a condition to a function in C++?

Tags: c++

I would like to have a function that runs some code until a given condition is met.  How can I pass a function to a function such that the end function calls the parameter function over and over until it outputs a given value?  Given that I will not be reusing the parameter function, I would prefer to not create a named function if possible.

Comment: [Use a lambda as a parameter for a C++ function](//stackoverflow.com/q/40844622)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I saw that but I’m not sure how to actually pass the function.  I don’t need to have any inputs on the function that is passed.  It will only output true or false.

Comment: I believe the link covers this, but here's an example: https://ideone.com/z8ycR5

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short example. Create a function that takes a lambda as an argument.

```
template<typename Func>
void myFunction(Func&& lambda){
    int i=1;
    while (lambda(i++)){
        std::cout << "Still running!\n";
    }
}
```

Call the function with the lambda as an argument

```
int main(){
      myFunction([](auto&& val){ return val < 4 ;}); 
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For simple predicates it can be better to pass the function object by value: for instance, this is how the standard library does it.